# The image file is inaccessible and is being ignored

Tags: virtualbox

I installed a Windows 8 from an ISO to VirtualBox running on Ubuntu.  Everything works fine, but I deleted the initial ISO that it was installed from.  Now I get the error in the title (it says it is a "Warning.")  Windows 8 still seems to work fine and I can shut it down, pause the virtual machine, etc. with no problems.  It seems like this is just a warning because the ISO was deleted.

- Is this just a warning?
- Why does VirtualBox care about the ISO post installation?
- Is there anything I should do to prevent the warning from popping up?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Right-click your virtual machine in the main Virtual Box window, go to Settings, then Storage. In there, you can see the original .iso is still being tried to be mounted. Just erase the mount point there and you're done.